# resize using imagemagick according to inches

Tags: image, imagemagick

I'm trying to find how to resize an image according to inches (not pixels) using ImageMagick. I'm newbie to image resizing. I made lot of research but I didn't find an option for inches. My aim is to resize a set of ".tiff" images so that they get a minimum width of 6.25 inches.

Comment: There is no direct way to resize according to inches. To do that you must compute the size in pixels from the inches you want and the density (resolution) in pixels per inch.  So for 6.25 inches at density=72, you need pixels size of 6.25*72=450 pixels. So you  would do `convert image -resize 450x450^ result`. See http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php#geometry for the use of ^, >, <.

Comment: Oh ok, I will read this and come back to you. Thanks

Comment: If you need a particular density for printing, then change 72 to your desired density. In ImageMagick 7, you can do it in one command line as `magick image -resize "%[fx:6.25/72]^" result` or create variables for inches=6.25 and density=72. Then use `magick image -resize "%[fx:$inches/$density]^" result`. In ImageMagick 6, you would create a variable for the pixel dimension first as `dim=$(convert xc: -format "%[fx:$inches/$density]" info:)`. Then `convert image -resize $dim^ result`.

Comment: You can also go the other way to make it print to 6.25 inches. Look at the meta data with `identify image`. Find the image dimension in pixels, then change the density for the image so that dimension/desired_density=6.25 in, where density is in units of pixelsperinch. This will only change the density and not the image dimensions, but will then print to 6.25 in. For example if your image is 6250 pixels, then 6250pixels/100pixelsperinch=6.25 in. So `convert image -density 100 -units pixelsperinch result`. That is desired_density=dimension/6.25=6250/6.25=100

Comment: Another option is to use EXIFTOOL to edit the density/resolution in the image's meta data. That way, if the image is jpg, there will be no further loss of quality by reading and writing (decompressing and recompressing) the image.

Comment: thank's for all for your responses. I choosed finally the solution of fmw42 since it was easy to do this.